# Compiling Jaeger gRPC proto files with Python

Tags: grpc, jaeger, grpc-python

I'm currently playing around with [Jaeger Query](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.16/architecture/#query) and trying to access its content through the [API](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.16/apis/#grpc-protobuf-stable), which uses gRPC. I'm not familiar with gRPC, but my understanding is that I need to use the Python gRPC compiler (grpcio_tools.protoc) on the relevant proto file to get useful Python definitions. What I'm trying to do is find out ways to access Jaeger Query by API, without the frontend UI.

Currently, I'm very stuck on compiling the proto files. Every time I try, I get dependency issues (*Import "fileNameHere" was not found or has errors.*). The Jaeger [query.proto](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/blob/master/model/proto/api_v2/query.proto) file contains import references to files outside the repo. Whilst I can find these and manually collect them, they also have dependencies. I get the impression that following through and collecting each of these one by one is not how this was intended to be done.

Am I doing something wrong here? The direct documentation through Jaeger is limited for this. The below is my basic terminal session, before including any manually found files (which themselves have dependencies I would have to go and find the files for).

```
$ python -m grpc_tools.protoc --grcp_python_out=. --python_out=. --proto_path=. query.proto
model.proto: File not found.
gogoproto/gogo.proto: File not found.
google/api/annotations.proto: File not found.
protoc-gen-swagger/options/annotations.proto: File not found.
query.proto:20:1: Import "model.proto" was not found or had errors.
query.proto:21:1: Import "gogoproto/gogo.proto" was not found or had errors.
query.proto:22:1: Import "google/api/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors.
query.proto:25:1: Import "protoc-gen-swagger/options/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors.
query.proto:61:12: "jaeger.api_v2.Span" is not defined.
query.proto:137:12: "jaeger.api_v2.DependencyLink" is not defined.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I should add that [the gRPC python tut](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python/) has been my bible so far, and I'm stuck on *Generating client and server code* section.

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine provided the answer... It was hidden in the Makefile, which hadn't worked for me as I don't use Golang (and it had been more complex than just installing Golang and running it, but I digress...).

The following .sh will do the trick. This assumes the query.proto file is a subdirectory from the same location as the script below, under model/proto/api_v2/ (as it appears in the main Jaeger repo).

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set +x

rm -rf ./js_out 2> /dev/null
mkdir ./js_out

PROTO_INCLUDES="
    -I model/proto \
    -I idl/proto \
    -I vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway \
    -I vendor/github.com/gogo/googleapis \
    -I vendor/github.com/gogo/protobuf/protobuf \
    -I vendor/github.com/gogo/protobuf"

python -m grpc_tools.protoc ${PROTO_INCLUDES} --grpc_python_out=./python_out --python_out=./python_out model/proto/api_v2/query.proto
```

This will definitely generate the needed Python file, but it will still be missing dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to get the Jaeger gRPC Python APIs:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-idl
cd jaeger-idl/
make proto
```

Use the files inside `proto-gen-python/`.

Note:
While importing the generated code, if you face the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'google.protobuf.descriptor' has no attribute '_internal_create_key'
```

Do:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --upgrade protobuf
```